# Is $\log(100 \cdot 10^x)$ the same as $\log_{10}(100 \cdot 10^x)$?

Tags: logarithms

I just learned about logarithms, and my question is:

> Is $\log(100 \cdot 10^x)$ the same as $\log_{10}(100 \cdot 10^x)$?

If so, why?

Comment: It's the question of definition. Usually it's used $\lg$ instead of $\log_{10}$. 
And $\log$ as $\log_{e}$

Comment: And in other contexts, $\lg$ often means $\log_2$ and $\log_e$ is often denoted by $\ln$. The bottom line is, when you see $\log$ without a base, think of whatever the base could be.

Comment: If I type the two logarithms in a math program, I get the same answer.

Comment: @Hilmar So within your math programm the short notation $\log(x)$ refers to the decadic logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is a little bit tricky. I have seen three important cases concerning the base conventions of logarithms

$$\begin{align}
&\text{The natural logarithm }&&\log_e(x)\text{ often denoted as }\ln(x)\text{ but also sometimes as }\log(x)\\
&\text{The decadic logarithm }&&\log_{10}(x)\text{ often denoted as }\lg(x)\text{ but also sometimes as }\log(x)\\
&\text{The binary logarithm }&&\log_2(x)\text{ often denoted as }\operatorname{ld}(x)\text{ or }\operatorname{lb}(x)\\
\end{align}$$

So it is a matter of context I would say but not a general fact that $\log(x)$ refers to the decadic one. I for myself tend to use $\log(x)$ for the natural logarithm.

Comment: Okay makes sense, thank you

Comment: @Hilmar In this case mark my answer as accepted to show that you so that other users know that you are satisfied:)

Answer (score 0):

depending where you are from, in some areas $\log(x)=\log_{10}(x)$ and $\ln(x)=log_{e}(x)$ whilst in other areas people take $\log(x)=\log_{e}(x)$ so it is best to use $\log_{10}(x)$ and $\ln(x)$ to make it clear.